# How to know if a machine can be pinged with c#?

Tags: c#, ping

I'm trying to test if my machine can be pinged by other network entities:

```
Type NetFwMgrType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwMgr", false);
INetFwMgr mgr = (INetFwMgr)Activator.CreateInstance(NetFwMgrType);
string allowed = mgr.LocalPolicy.CurrentProfile.IcmpSettings.AllowInboundEchoRequest;
```

Comment: Why not use the [`System.Net.Networkinformation.Ping`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) class?

Comment: @WaiHaLee maybe post this ans an answer since it is the answer? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to know whether a machine can get pinged; the ICMP type 8 in and type 0 out need to be allowed.

```
public Boolean IsPingable()
    {
        Boolean icmpAllowed = false;
        INetFwMgr mgr = (INetFwMgr)Activator.CreateInstance(NetFwMgrType);
        Object allowedin8 = null;
        Object restrictedin8 = null;
        Object allowedout0 = null;
        Object restrictedout0 = null;
      mgr.IsIcmpTypeAllowed(NET_FW_IP_VERSION_.NET_FW_IP_VERSION_V4,"127.0.0.1", 0, out allowedin0, out restrictedin0);
      mgr.IsIcmpTypeAllowed(NET_FW_IP_VERSION_.NET_FW_IP_VERSION_V4, "8.8.8.8", 8, out allowedout8, out restrictedout8);
        if ((Boolean)allowedin0 && (Boolean)allowedout8)
        {
            icmpAllowed = true;
        }
        return icmpAllowed;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send a ping to check if it can be pinged:

```
public static bool CanBePinged(string hostname)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(hostname)) throw new ArgumentException("hostname");

    Ping p1 = new Ping();
    try
    {
        PingReply PR = p1.Send(hostname);
        return PR.Status == IPStatus.Success;
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`System.Net.Networkinformation.Ping`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping)`.Send(...)`.

You can use `Ping` in several ways, including specifying a host name, in which case [the MSDN sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7hzczzed) is:

> ```
> public static void SimplePing ()
> {
>     Ping pingSender = new Ping ();
>     PingReply reply = pingSender.Send ("www.contoso.com");
>
>     if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
>     {
>         Console.WriteLine ("Address: {0}", reply.Address.ToString ());
>         Console.WriteLine ("RoundTrip time: {0}", reply.RoundtripTime);
>         Console.WriteLine ("Time to live: {0}", reply.Options.Ttl);
>         Console.WriteLine ("Don't fragment: {0}", reply.Options.DontFragment);
>         Console.WriteLine ("Buffer size: {0}", reply.Buffer.Length);
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         Console.WriteLine (reply.Status);
>     }
> }
> ```

or you can specify an [`IPAddress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress), in which case [the MSDN sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hb7xxkfx) is:

> ```
> public static void LocalPing ()
> {
>     // Ping's the local machine.
>     Ping pingSender = new Ping ();
>     IPAddress address = IPAddress.Loopback;
>     PingReply reply = pingSender.Send (address);
>
>     if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
>     {
>         Console.WriteLine ("Address: {0}", reply.Address.ToString ());
>         Console.WriteLine ("RoundTrip time: {0}", reply.RoundtripTime);
>         Console.WriteLine ("Time to live: {0}", reply.Options.Ttl);
>         Console.WriteLine ("Don't fragment: {0}", reply.Options.DontFragment);
>         Console.WriteLine ("Buffer size: {0}", reply.Buffer.Length);
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         Console.WriteLine (reply.Status);
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: I'm not trying to see if I can ping a remote machine, but whether my machine can be pinged?

Comment: In the first sample, you can change `"www.contoso.com"` to `localhost` and remove the `"Time to live"` and `"Don't fragment"` lines (they will throw `NullReferenceException`s) and it'll let you know if your machine responds to pings. The second sample is **already** using [`IPAddress.Loopback`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.loopback) which will ping your (the local) machine.

Comment: It returns a success status when the machine can't be pinged.!!